# White screen after dismissing UIImagePickerController on iOS 5?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a problem with a published app where (some) users who are running iOS 5 will (sometimes) see a white screen after dismissing a `UIImagePickerController` in my app. This only started occurring after iOS 5 was released.

It only occurs for some people (I can't reproduce on any of my test devices) but I have seen it in person on other people's phones.

The strange thing is that restarting the phone fixes it - permanently. I tried on a friend's brand-new iPhone 4S. They downloaded my app, opened the image picker, selected an image - white screen. Then I restarted the phone and it has never happened since.

Any idea what could cause this or where I should be looking for fixes?

Comment: Have you filed a bug with Apple and/or looked at the devices crash reports? Both of those might be helpful places to look.

Comment: I've seen `UIImagePickerController` have issues with not being able to return the edited image before, although that was back on the 3G mainly. I'd check your logic after the image picker returns an image and check it handles the case of `nil` image properly. Just a thought though.

Comment: @Moshe, the app doesn't actually crash, so the device logs look normal up until the point where the white screen appears, at which point log output just stops until I close the app. Filing a radar is a good idea - I'll do that now.

Answer (score 2):

this is probably a memory problem: the UIImagePickerController might use a lot of memory, such that the viewDidUnload method of your 
UIViewController showing a white screen, so you don't see anything.

if you restart your phone most memory of your iphone is free, so a memory problem is less likely.

take a look at the section Memory Management of the call reference of [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

how do you create your ViewController? XIB or by code with loadView or viewDidLoad ?

Comment: With code in loadView. I thought that, too, but it happens right away the first time you try it on a new phone (reproducibly) and then never, ever happens again.

Comment: even if you delete the app, reboot the iphone and reinstall the app?

Comment: Not sure, I'll have to find the friend who had the phone where I could reproduce it.